# Combobox SelectedItem property return always and show always the first item

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, selecteditem

I have 3 combobox `ObjetivosCB`, `FrecuenciasCB` and `ResponsablesCB` in my form as shows below

```
public partial class Form_Indicador : Form
{
    public Indicador Indicador { get; set; }
    private void Form_AgregarIndicador_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Indicador == null)
            Indicador = new Indicador();

        ConfigurarObjetivosCB();
        ConfigurarFrecuenciasCB();
        ConfigurarResponsablesCB();

        CargarPropiedadesIndicador();
    }

    private void ConfigurarResponsablesCB()
    {
        ResponsableCB.DataSource = ResponsableRepository.Instance.All();
        ResponsableCB.DisplayMember = "Area";
        if (Indicador.Responsable == null) 
            ResponsableCB.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }

    private void ConfigurarFrecuenciasCB()
    {           
        FrecuenciasCB.DisplayMember = "Periodo";
        FrecuenciasCB.DataSource = IndicadorRepository.Instance.AllFrecuencias();       
        if (Indicador.Frecuencia == null) 
            FrecuenciasCB.SelectedIndex = -1;   
    }

    private void ConfigurarObjetivosCB()
    {
        ObjetivosCB.DataSource = _objetivoFachada.All();
        ObjetivosCB.DisplayMember = "Nombre";
        if (Indicador.Objetivo == null) ObjetivosCB.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }

    private void CargarPropiedadesIndicador()
    {            
        ObjetivosCB.DataBindings.Add("SelectedItem", Indicador, "Objetivo");
        ResponsableCB.DataBindings.Add("SelectedItem", Indicador, "Responsable");
        FrecuenciasCB.DataBindings.Add("SelectedItem", Indicador, "Frecuencia");
    }
```

}

The problem is that `FrecuenciasCB.SelectedItem` and `ResponsablesCB.SelectedItem` always show and return the first item but `ObjetivosCB.SelectedItem` works fine. I am not understand... three methods has the same logic. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do `ResponsableRepository.Instance.All()`,`_IndicadorRepository.Instance.AllFrecuencias()` and `_objetivoFachada.All()` return?

Comment: Return `IList<Responsable>`, `IList<Indicador>` and `IList<Objetivo>` respectively.

Comment: You set the `DisplayMember` property *after* the `DataSource` in the third Configure method. I'm unsure if this matters, but it's worth checking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been solved! The problem was a wrong definition for `Equals()` in `Indicador` and `Frecuencia`.